# How to solve dynamic meta tags in Angular ssr?

Tags: angular, meta-tags, angular-universal

I have an angular application with server side rendering. I am loading the meta tags content dynamicaly from backend. However in the html i see the meta tags with the proper content, the facebook debugger cant recognize the tags. Somebody faced with this issue?

I tried fill the meta tags in the component onInit func and fill the tags in a resolver.

Comment: I created [these directives](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-seo/src/lib/directives/seo/seo.directive.ts) which you need to use [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/blob/master/apps/seo-demo/src/app/pages/home/home.component.html#L2). This way you don't need to clean up your tags manually. It happens automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create service RoutMetaService

```
 export class RoutMetaService {
 constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta) {}

updateTitle(title: string) {
this.title.setTitle(title);
 }

updateOgUrl(url: string) {
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:url', content: url });
console.log('updateOgUrl');
}

updateDescription(desc: string) {
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc });
 }
updateKeywords(key: string) {
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: key });
 }
}
```

> in routing.module.ts

```
      {
    path: "path name",
    component: Your Component,
    data: {
      title: "Title Page",
      description: "Description Meta Tag Content",
      ogUrl: "your og url",
      keywords: " Keywords Meta Tag Content ",
    },
  },
```

> In your typescript components constructor

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private routMeta: RoutMetaService
 ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.activatedRoute),
    map((route) => {
      while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
      return route;
    }),
    filter((route) => route.outlet === "primary"),
    mergeMap((route) => route.data)
  )
  .subscribe((event: any) => {
   //Updating Description tag dynamically with title
    this.routMeta.updateTitle(event["title"]);
    //Updating Description tag dynamically with ogUrl
    this.routMeta.updateOgUrl(event["ogUrl"]);
     //Updating Description tag dynamically with description
    this.routMeta.updateDescription(event["description"]);
    //Updating Description tag dynamically with keywords
    this.routMeta.updateKeywords(event["keywords"]);
    });
  }
```

> in index.html

```
 <title>title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. After that I realized i have implemented it almost the same way. The reason that it does not work for me, that i had a line in my code:
`const url: string = window.location.href;`
And this code does not interpretable on serverside, so the angular ssr has fallen back to csr mode. That was the reason why seo debuggers couldnt grab the meta tags.